# How to compare two input variables with mysql stored values (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql

I basicaly want to make an HTML form in which the user inserts two different inputs. 
 These inputs are then compared with data stored in a MySQL table. If BOTH of the input variables match two variables located IN A SAME ROW from the table, it returns a message, if not it returns another.
  How can I do this? This is my code so far:

`if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {`
  `echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  }`

// escape variables for security

`$numero_cedula = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['numero_cedula']);`
`$codigo= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['codigo']);`

`$sql1="select`Numero Cedula`from Teste where`Numero Cedula`=$numero_cedula";`

`mysqli_query($con,$sql1);`

`$sql2="select`Codigo`from Teste where`Codigo`=$codigo";`

`mysqli_query($con,$sql2);`

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). It's only in exceptional circumstances you'll need to call the escaping function manually.

Answer (score 0):

- Modify your query to use `AND` in the `WHERE` clause
- Check the returned row count with [**`mysqli_num_rows`**](https://www.php.net/mysqli_num_rows)
- Do some small [**`if()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) logic.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$numero_cedula = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['numero_cedula']);
$codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['codigo']);
$sql1 = "SELECT `Numero Cedula` 
         FROM Teste 
         WHERE `Numero Cedula`=$numero_cedula
           AND `Codigo`=$codigo";
$objGet = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

if( mysqli_num_rows($objGet) > 0 ) {
  echo "Duplicate";
} else {
  echo "Not a duplicate";
}
```